# Rewrite second URL Parameter htaccess

Tags: url-rewriting

I have searched in SO but never came across this specific answer. If anyone can help.

This use to be my URL structure **/index.php?param1=is1** and I got it to look like this **/is1** by using this Rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index\.php)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Do not ask my how I got this as it's been a while that this was written. Now the issue is i have a second parameter. So my url that is like this **/index.php?param1=is1&param2=is2** needs to be like this **/is1/is2**.

Obviously, now it's like this **/is1&param2=is2**. So i guess what I am searching for is a way to ask if **&param2=** is seen than hide it ?

I really don't get the logic behind all this URLREWRITE. I am trying to clean my URL structure for SEO purposes and COPY/PASTE logic as URL's should be shared between different users / clients. Obviously, having **/this-is-something&this=that** is not that bad but having **/this-is-something/that** is much better.

Just for info, first parameters is BRANDS **/this-is-my-brand1** or **/this-is-my-brand2** and second parameter is a product as **/this-is-my-brand1/product1** before all that I use to have **/index.php?brand=brand-one&product=product-one**. Changing everything is not an issue, I can start from scratch if there is anything better than what I have.

I am on the learning curve, so I don't mind long explanations.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your request parameters name are static (never change) you can use a more specifiq rule

```
RewriteRule  ^(.+)/(.+)$  index.php?brand=$1&product=$2 [L]
```